# Does Django support JOIN?

Tags: django, django-orm

Does Django ORM support join like INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN AND OUTER JOIN?

I read the document, and did not found one.

For example how can I do this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM auth_user_groups
JOIN test_groups ON auth_user_groups.group_id=test_groups.group_id
WHERE test_id='1'
AND user_id='2'
LIMIT 1
```

test_group is a Many to many table, without any model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Use [relational fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) and [appropriately-crafted queries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to perform joins instead.

Comment: This isn't quite the same. Each time you do `foo.bar_set` it does a database query.