# How does Django handle JOIN like filter statements?

Tags: django, django-models

I have some code that consists of 3 models, namely Course, Section and Lecture.
A Course has many sections, a Section has many Lectures. Say i want to retrieve all the Lectures that belong to a particular Course, Course also has a property called 'title' so thats what will be used to filter. According to the tutorial i'm reading i should do this to get the lectures:

`Lecture.objects.filter(section__course__title = "title of course)`

This is pretty straightforward but what i'm wondering is how django is handling this under the hood. Some joins must be involved i can imagine, but according to the answer of this thread [Does Django support JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001744/does-django-support-join) Django cannot make Joins.
But when i look at the links he provides i can read that django does handle joins behind the scenes.

So lets assume django does handle joins, how does it know when to make a left join or a regular join? A regular join can only be made when it is certain that every parent model has a reference to a child model, the field is marked not null. If it can be null then a left join should be used. Is django intelligent enough to know when to make which join?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The django ORM will be performing the join operations for you under the hood it abstracts away a lot of the complexity.

If you run the code below should will be able to see the SQL which django generates.

```
quseryset = Lecture.objects.filter(section__course__title = "title of course")
print(queryset.query)
```

It is explained in the django docs: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)